# Baryon number vs electromagnetic charge, what is the difference?

Tags: subatomic, baryons

What exactly is a Baryon number? I looked up definition from wikipedia and still struggle to understand this. And how does this differ than the
electromagnetic charge?

My textbook did the following computation:

[image]

It is calculating the electromagnetic charge right and not the Baryon number?

Answer (score 1):

[Baryon number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number) ($B$) and [electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) ($q$) are different quantities.
Both quantities are useful because both obey their own [conservation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law).

To make this more clear consider the proton ($p$), the neutron ($n$),
their constituent quarks ($u$ and $d$), and the electron ($e$).
Proton and neutron have the same baryon number,
but different electric charges.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{particle} & B  & q \\ \hline
 p\ (uud) & 1  & +e \\ \hline
 n\ (udd) & 1  & 0 \\ \hline
 u & \frac 13 & +\frac 23 e \\ \hline
 d & \frac 13 & -\frac 13 e \\ \hline
 e & 0 & -e
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

A *baryon* is any particle held together by the strong force (i.e. a type of *hadron*) that comprises three quarks. An *antibaryon* has three antiquarks.

The baryon number $B$ is just the sum of all the quarks $n_q$ minus the sum of all the anti-quarks $n_{\bar q}$ :

$$ B = \frac{1}{3}(n_q-n_{\bar q}).$$

So, a quark has baryon number $B = 1/3$, an antiquark $B = -1/3$, baryons have $B = +1$, antibaryons have $B=-1$, mesons have $B=0$ and so on.

A proton, in your example, has $3$ quarks and hence has a $B=1$. Just $1$, a natural number. No units.

Its quarks are $u$, $u$, and $d$, so if we perform the *separate* and *independent* from the above sum of the electric charge we get:
$$ q = q_u + q_u + q_d = 2e/3 + 2e/3 -1e/3 = 1e.$$

So the total electromagnetic charge of a proton is $q = 1e = 1.60 \times 10^{-19}$ C.

The baryon number of a proton is $1$.

Comment: I found this while looking for the same thing. I think OP (and myself) are wondering what is the point in a quantity called 'Baryon' number when you have charge as well? Does it become useful and unique in different situations?

Comment: I guess for situations involving neutral objects that don't couple to EM, baryon number conservation still counts.

Comment: Yes that makes sense to me, thank you.

Comment: But are they associated with the same U(1) phase? Or different?

Comment: they're totally different things, not the same U(1).